# Explanation for this simple looking haskell program (dynamic programming)

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

This is the program which counts number of ways to partition one dollar. I don't understand the line `c = a ++ zipWith (+) b c` as before this line c is not declared before this then how can we zip b and c? (I'm new to haskell, a good explanation is appreciated)

```
import Data.List
change [] = 1 : repeat 0
change (d : ds) = c where
  (a, b) = splitAt d (change ds)
  c = a ++ zipWith (+) b c
result = change [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50] !! 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
change [] = 1 : repeat 0
change (d : ds) = c where
  (a, b) = splitAt d (change ds)
  c = a ++ zipWith (+) b c
```

Then,

```
result = (!! 100) $ xs 
  where 
    xs = change [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50] 
       = let -- g = (\(a,b)-> fix ((a++) . zipWith (+) b)) 
             g (a,b) = let c = a ++ zipWith (+) b c in c
         in 
           g . splitAt 1 . change $ [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50]
         = g . splitAt 1 .
           g . splitAt 5 . change $ [10, 15, 20, 25, 50]
         = ....
         = let h n = g . splitAt n 
           in
             h 1 . h 5 . h 10 . h 15 . h 20 . h 25 . h 50 . (1:) . repeat $ 0
```

or, simpler,

```
Prelude> (!! 100) $ foldr h (1:cycle [0]) [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50]
1239
```

(which is a correct answer, BTW). This is arguably easier to comprehend. Your question is thus localized to the `g` definition,

```
    g (a,b) = let c = a ++ zipWith (+) b c in c
```

The thing about Haskell's definitions is that they are *recursive* (they are equivalent to Scheme's `letrec`, not `let`).

Here it works, because when `c` is *lazily* consumed, it's definition says it's built from two parts, `a ++ ...` and so first `a` is consumed. And this works because `a` does not depend on `c`. Calculating `a` does not demand any knowledge of `c`.

In `zipWith (+) b c`, `c` is essentially a ***pointer*** into the sequence being defined, `length a` notches ***back*** from the production point, `rest`, in this re-write:

```
    g (a,b) = 
      let c = a ++ rest
          rest = zipWith (+) b c
      in c
```

We have `h n xs = g (splitAt n xs)` and this is describing then the sum of the input list with the result, moved `n` notches forward:

```
    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 ................ xs     A
                   y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 .......... ys     B
    --------
    y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7.................... ys == A + B
```

This suggests `h` can be re-written with improved locality of access,

```
change ds n = foldr h (1:cycle [0]) ds !! n  -- [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50] 100
  where
    h n xs = ys where ys = zipWith (+) xs (replicate n 0 ++ ys)
        -- = fix (zipWith (+) xs . (replicate n 0 ++))
```

Answer (score 2):

`y = f y` is equivalent to infinite chain of applications: `y = f ( f ( f ( f (...

so `c = a ++ (zipWith (+) b c)` is equivalent to c = a ++ (zipWith (+) b (a ++ (zipWith (+) b (...)))

Answer (score 2):

This is a particularly complicated use of recursive definitions.  Both 'change' and 'c' are defined in terms of themselves.

'change _' is an infinitely long singly-linked list of Integer.

This 'c' is also and infinitely long singly-linked list of Integer.

What is the first element of 'a ++ ... ' ?  If 'a' is not-empty (and here it is not empty since the list passes to change is all positive) then it is the first element of 'a'.

In fact 'a' has length '1' in the first change, then '5' then '10' until the last 'a' has length '50'.

So the first element(s) of 'c' are taken from 'a'.  Then, once those run out, the following elements of 'c' come from 'zipWith (+) b c'.

Now 'b' and 'c' are infinitely long singly-linked lists of Integer.

The first element of 'b' comes from part of the recursive call to 'change _' after the 'a' portion.  The first part of 'c' is the 'a' portion.

Let the length of the 'a' portion by 5, and also call 'a' by name 'p1'.

```
c = (5 elements of 'a', call this p1)
  ++ (5 elements of zipWith (+) p1 b, call this p2)
  ++ (5 elements of zipWith (+) p2 (drop 5 b), call this p3)
  ++ (5 elements of zipWith (+) p3 (drop 10 b) ++...
```